# Induced extension of function fields for $k$-linear frobenius.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth curve over $k$ algebraically closed of characteristic $p > 0$, with function field $K$.

Let $X_p$ denote the $k$ sheme $X \to k \stackrel{F}\to k$ the same scheme but with a different structural morphism (twisted by the frobenius $F: k \to k$). Then, the Frobenius endomorphism of $X$ induces a $k$-linear map $X_p \to X$. Hartshorne (IV.2.4.3) then claims that this is induced by the field extension $K \hookrightarrow K^{1/p}$ but I don't understand this.

Rather, it seems to me that this map is the one $K \to K$ given by $f \mapsto f^p$, or rather the field extension $K^p \hookrightarrow K$. Where am I going wrong? Are these somehow the same field extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field extensions $K\to K^{1/p}$ and $K^p\to K$ are isomorphic.  Indeed, $K^{1/p}$ is isomorphic to $K$ via the map $f\mapsto f^p$ and this sends the subfield $K\subseteq K^{1/p}$ to the subfield $K^p\subseteq K$.  If you want to think of $X_p\to X$ as corresponding to an extension of the function field of $X$, then it is more natural to call it $K\to K^{1/p}$, since you want an extension of $K$.